# ExtJS: Checkbox check should not select in tree node

Tags: extjs, extjs5

When Checkbox checked, it selecting the node and triggering 'select' listener (actually it triggers all kinds of click, cellclick events also)

I have two different functionalities for checkbox check and selecting the node. So now i am unable to differentiate check and select.

```
Ext.define("App.view.search.resultTree", {
extend: "Ext.tree.Panel",
alias: 'widget.resultTree',
id: 'resultTree',
title: 'Results',
rootVisible: false,
useArrows: true,
border: 0,
autoScroll: true,
height: 680,

emptyText: Messages.EmptyText.NoDataFound,

viewModel: {
    type: "resultViewModel"
},

store: Ext.create('Somestore'),

listeners: {
    checkchange: function (node, checked) {

        node.eachChild(function (n) {
            node.cascadeBy(function (n) {
                    n.set('checked', checked);
                }
            );
        });


    },

    rowmousedown:function(){
        console.log('in rowmouse down');
    },

    itemclick:function(){
        console.log('in itemclick');
    },

    cellclick: function(){
        console.log('in cellclick');
    },

    select: function(){
        console.log('in selection');
    }
}
})
```

Comment: A little bit of code or a fiddle would help to understand your setup. Is it something like this: http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/examples/kitchensink/?profile=classic#check-tree ?

Comment: i have added the code

Comment: @ASP your example is also selecting the node when check the checkbox. But i dont want to select the record when check the checkbox.